# Then $bP$ is a projective $Ab$-module.

Tags: projective-module, free-modules

$A$ is a $k$-algebra and $b$ is an idempotent in $Z(A)$.
Let $P$ be a projective $A$-module. Then $bP$ is a projective $Ab$-module.

Here is my proof:
$P$ is a direct summand of a free $A$-module and hence a direct summand of a free $Ab$-module since $A = A(1-b)\oplus Ab$ and $A(1-b) \cong Ab$. So since $bP$ is a direct summand of $P$, it's projective as a $Ab$-module.

Any verification would be appreciated!

Comment: That's fine. Only complaint would be that $e$ is a more traditional letter for an idempotent!

Comment: hahaha  thx, Angina!